# Чи є можливість розрізнити російські "логичньій" і "логический" українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Російською можна сказати два вирази:

- Логичная формула (яка логічна в цій ситуації тощо)
- Логическая формула (напр. формула з логіки висловлювань)

Кожен з них має своє значення. Українською обидва слова мають той самий [переклад](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

> **Логи́ческий, Логи́чный** – логі́чний.

Як краще українською передати цю різницю?

Comment: _Логическая формула_ — це, я так розумію, в цьому випадку _[булева формула](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Булева_формула)_?

Comment: @Sasha, так булева це один з підвидів, та можуть бути й інші види.

Comment: Можливо підійде варіант: "Питання з логіки"?

Answer (score 3):

"Логичный" російською означає закономірний, розумний, послідовний. 
Тому, наприклад, "логический вопрос" перекладається як "логічне запитання", а "логичный вопрос" — "закономірне питання".

Comment: Ставлю мінус, додайте, будь ласка, джерела, постарайтесь завести відповідь у контекст питання.

Answer (score 1):

Перш за все, я звернувся до Гугл перекладача, однак він переклав і "логичный" і "логический" як "логічний". Цей [перекладач](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) також переклав ці слова ідентично, однак давайте подивимося на приклади перекладу слова "логичный":

> Не **логично** ли, что... - Чи не **розсудливо** було б тоді
>   припустити...
>   Да. И это, кажется, не только **логично** - Так. Це, здається, не
>   тільки **має сенс**.

А от слово "логический" набагато частіше перекладають як "логічний" чи "змістовий":

> Всегда очень трудно выстроить **логическую** линию в таких фильмах о
>   репрессиях - У фільмах про репресії важко **логічно** розвинути сюжет.
>
> Правильное **логическое** ударение - **Змістовий** наголос

Крім того, варто зазначити, що згідно до [Словника російських синонімів](http://jeck.ru/tools/SynonymsDictionary/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) "логичный" і "логический" можуть бути синонімами, а в такому випадку і переклад цих слів може бути однаковим.

Отож, якщо ми подивимося етимологію цих слів, то побачимо, що всі вони походять від давньогрецького слова "логіка", а тому й не дивно, що вони мають схоже значення, а в деякому контексті можуть виступати синонімами, але як бачимо, зазвичай слово "логический" перекладають саме як "логічний", а от "логичный" можна перекласти як "той, що має сенс", "розсдуливе (наприклад про рішення) тощо. Ще раз повторю, переклад як одного, так і другого слова буде залежати від контексту.